# Spring Data - Mongo DB - search for results where multiple search- strings are contained

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have an Entity class in my application using spring data and mongoDB which looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = "DocumentFile")
public class DocumentFile {

private String originalFileName;
```

and now I want to create a search method for the field **originalFileName**.
The name of originalFileName e.g. can look like this:

> testFileName-2016-USA.pdf

I will search e.g. for **FileName** AND **2016** and the file mentioned above should be match.
My question now would be how I can do this. I would need a method like this:

```
public interface DocumentFileRepository extends MongoRepository<DocumentFile , String> {

    List<DocumentFile> findDocumentFilesByOriginalFileNameContaining(final List<String> searchStrings);

}
```

Is there a possibility to do that like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `In` Keyword Query Method.

If you see the reference documentation the keyword In searches a column/pair key row/value stored.

Example in [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries):

> In   - findByAgeIn(Collection ages)  -  {"age" : {"$in" : [ages…​]}}

So in your case you could do something like:

`List<DocumentFile> findByOriginalFileNameIn(final Collection<String> searchStrings);`